# how to efficiently rename a lot of blobs in GCS

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

Lets say that on Google Cloud Storage I have bucket: *bucket1* and inside this bucket I have thousands of blobs I want to rename in this way:

**Original blob**:
*bucket1/subfolder1/subfolder2/data_filename.csv*

**to**: *bucket1/subfolder1/subfolder2/data_filename/data_filename_backup.csv*

`subfolder1`, `subfolder2` and `data_filename.csv` - they can have different names, however the way to change names of all blobs is as above.

What is the most efficient way to do this? Can I use Python for that?

Comment: Since you have a logic involved in process, its better to do via python.

Answer (score 1):

You can use whatever programming language you want where Google offers an SDK for working with Cloud Storage.  There is not going to be much of an advantage to any particular language you choose.

There is not really an "efficient" way of doing this.  What you will end up doing in your code is pretty standard:

1. [List the objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects) that you want to rename.
2. Iterate that list.
3. For each object, [change the name](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/copying-renaming-moving-objects#rename).

You will get better performance overall if you run the code in a Google Cloud Shell or other Google Cloud compute environment in the same region as your bucket.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of rename to perform, I recommend to perform the operation concurrently (use several thread and not perform the rename sequentially).

Indeed, you have to know how works CLoud Storage. `rename` doesn't exist. You can go into the Python library and see what is done: `copy` then `delete`.

The copy can take time if your files are large. Delete is pretty fast. But in both case, it's API call and it take time (about 50ms if you are in the same region).

If you can perform 200 or 500 operations concurrently, you will significantly reduce the processing time. It's easier with Go or Node, but you can do the same in Python with `await` key word.

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample python code which you can use..

```
from google.cloud import storage

# authentication........
client = storage.Client()
bucket_name = 'bucket_name'
bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blobs = bucket.list_blobs()

for blob in blobs:
    original_blob_name = blob.name
    # Extract the filename without extension
    filename_without_extension = original_blob_name.rsplit('.', 1)[0]
    # Construct the new blob name with the "_backup" suffix
    new_blob_name = f"{filename_without_extension}/{filename_without_extension}_backup.csv"
    # Rename the blob
    new_blob = bucket.rename_blob(blob, new_blob_name)
    print(f"Renamed blob: {original_blob_name} to {new_blob.name}")
```